# Customize Grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm varely new with iOS and I'm working on a simple application that requires a grouped UITableView. I managed to setup the UITableView programatically and now I'm down to the styling part. This is a subject I'm having trouble with.

How am I able to achieve the design in the example below? So how am I able to create the grouped UITableView without the OUTER border, but drop a shadow on there instead?

[image]

Comment: @MikePollard: haha, loved it !

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your own `UITableViewCell`, have a look at this [example](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/prettykit)

and then you can add the `UITextField` as a subView of the cell. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom UITableViewCell by subclassing it.

then add your required controls in that.

now create instances of this customized cells in CellForRowWithIndexPath

Comment: But each cell is different right? What about the top and bottom cells?